# Using asyncio in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have just started learning asyncio in Python, and wrote the following code:

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def hello():
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(3):
        loop.run_until_complete(hello())
    loop.close()
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Hello
<waits for 3 seconds>
World
Hello
<waits for 3 seconds>
World
Hello
<waits for 3 seconds>
World
```

How can I modify the program so that the same is handled asynchronously (i.e. once the first task sleeps, the second one begins executing), essentially giving output similar to this:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
World
World
World
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `asyncio.gather` them.

```
import asyncio


async def hello():
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("World")

async def lots_of_hello():
    cur_list = []
    for _ in range(3):
        cur_list.append(hello())
    await asyncio.gather(*cur_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(lots_of_hello())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Don't we need to perform loop.close()?

Comment: We do, added :) @Mihika

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to asyncio, but I got curious reading your question and tried to explore it a little bit. This is what I got, something different than the previous answer, with an extra candy of variable sleep time ;) :

```
import asyncio


async def hello(timeToSleep):
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(timeToSleep)
    print("World")

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(3):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(hello(i)))
    for task in tasks:
        await task

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```